# Handle event inside function

Tags: vb.net, function, events, handler

Is there a way to get an event handler inside a function? I need to handle a Tick event (t.Tick). Here's what I mean:

```
    Public Shared Function SetTime(ByVal x As Label)
    Dim t As New Timer
    t.Enabled = True
    t.Interval = 100
    t.Start()
    'I need the handler here
    x.Text = Date.Now.ToShortTimeString()
    'I need the handler to end here
    Return True
End Function
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Handler for which event? What's happening? Are you trying to include `x` as part of the handler's logic?

Comment: The X is a label, I'm trying to set the labels text to the current time every 100 MS, I got the timer working (i believe) and i just need the handler. I explained the event i needed, so i dont understand how you missed that.

Comment: For your convenience, i need the t.Tick event.

Comment: No. The Tick handler is a Sub, you can't put inside another function. Just put the code to update the label inside the Tick handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Tick` event handle needs to be a separate Sub. When you create your timer, you can provide the address of the Sub that will handle the `Tick` event. You will need to store a reference to the `Label` in a class level variable.

```
Private Shared timeLabel As Label, myTimer As Timer

Public Shared Function SetTime(ByVal x As Label) As Boolean
    timeLabel = x

    myTimer = New Timer
    myTimer.Enabled = True
    myTimer.Interval = 100
    AddHandler myTimer.Tick, AddressOf myTimer_Tick
    myTimer.Start()
    Return True
End Function

Private Shared Sub myTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    timeLabel.Text = Date.Now.ToShortTimeString()
End Sub
```

Comment: That Timer won't be garbage collected.  Move the declaration of the timer to the form's scope level.

Comment: I have to have it shared, because i need to call it from another form. This function is in a class, by the way.

Comment: No you don't have to have it Shared in order to call it from another form. It just has to be Public.

Comment: If the Function is in the NitAPI class, call it using an instance of the NitAPI class. not the class name. If, for some reason, you don't want to creat an instance of the NitAPI class, make `timeLabel` and `myTimer` as well as the Tick handler Shared as well.

Comment: @NITPRUDO I have edited my answer to make everything shared. You should also have a way to stop and dispose of the Timer.